# Accessing sharepoint web services in Silverlight app Error

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2007

I am currently trying to host my silverlight app on sharepoint in a content editor webpart.
But keep getting the error "The remote server returned an error: NotFound".  Is this a problem with the SL app not having access to the web service or something else?
I have added the clientaccesspolicy.xml file on the root of the site using SharePoint Designer. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your Silverlight control trying to do? Does it show up in the page and then, when trying to connect somewhere, it shows the error message?

Comment: I'm am tryin to display the contents of a sharepoint list, say 1 column.  Currently when I load the page nothing shows in the silverlight area only if I debug in Visual Studio I get the error.  I'm  using sharepoint web services to connect to the list to display in the Silverlight area. One solution I have tried is to put a clientaccessplicy.xml in the root of the site using sharepoint designer but this has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add to the url you are trying to use to connect to webservice from Silverlight, the clientaccesspolicy.xml? for instance, the url http://abc/clientaccesspolicy.xml should lead you to the content of this xml.

The second problem could be that your xml file is not correct. Which Silverlight version you are using?

as a example, here you have working clientaccesspolicy.xml for Silverlight 3.0 (checked on my IIS7)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: I tried that and I got the contents of the of my clientaccesspolicy.xml.  I don't think there is a problem with the xml. I found a suggestion on another site where they suggested using Fiddler to see where my app was getting a problem.  I realised the problem was that even though I created a web service that acccesses lists.asmx to look for my sharepoint list in a specified subsite it was looking for the list at the top level instead.  Even though this is not what I want I was able to resolve the problem by putting my list containing the data I wanted to pull on the top level site.

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense.